# WordPress Pagination problem for one category - pagination fix

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, advanced-custom-fields

somebody tried to fix pagination problem on my site by adding a function to your functions.php file[![screenshot - console][1]][1]

unfortunately, after updating wordpress or acf, this function does not work and when you try to go to the next page in the "atom" category, it displays 404 - Sorry, this page does not exist.

The pagination problem concerns only one category (subcategory). In the functions.php file I found a function like this:

````
function fix_atom_category_paged_query( $q ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_category( 'atom' ) && $_GET['debug'] == 1 ) {
        $q->set( 'post_type', 'post' );
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 9 );
        // wp_die( var_dump( $q ) );
        return $q;
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'fix_atom_category_paged_query', 2, 1 ); ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKqzT.png
````

Comment: It is difficult to understand from your question what exactly should be working and how but from that code I can see that it'll work only when $_GET['debug'] == 1 and you are NOT a logged-in admin.

Comment: for page: [link]example.com/category/atom/ pagination is not working. Somebody added code to functrions.php that was supposed to fix it. Unfortunately, this code does not work. I found some warnings related to ACF plug in console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKqzT.png

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem with the category called "atom" is due to the canonical link building and the wordpress core build itself. Names such as rss, feed, rss2, rdf, atom may conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tested it on another site. If category is called "atom", then wordpress pagination does not work for the archive of this category. I think this is WordPress problem.